# How to make a fittable Ring Gaussian model in python?

Tags: python, gaussian, ring, astropy, model-fitting

The purpose of my experiment is to fit a ring gaussian model to image data and find out the parameters of elliptical or ring Gaussian object in an image.

I've tried Astropy to make a Ring Gaussian model for simplicity and trial. Unfortunately, it's completely different from my artificial data.

```
from astropy.modeling import Fittable2DModel, Parameter, fitting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class ringGaussian(Fittable2DModel):

    background = Parameter(default=5.)
    amplitude = Parameter(default=1500.)
    x0 = Parameter(default=15.)
    y0 = Parameter(default=15.)
    radius = Parameter(default=2.)
    width = Parameter(default=1.)

    @staticmethod
    def evaluate(x, y, background, amplitude, x0, y0, radius, width):
        z = background + amplitude * np.exp( -((np.sqrt((x-x0)**2. + (y-y0)**2.) - radius) / width)**2 )
        return z
```

Then I made some artificial data (initial parameters) to test the fitting function of ring gaussian class.

```
back = 10 # background
amp = 2000 # highest value of the Gaussian
x0 = 10 # x coordinate of center
y0 = 10 # y coordinate of center
radius = 3
width = 1
xx, yy = np.mgrid[:30, :30]
z = back + amp * np.exp( -((np.sqrt((xx-x0)**2. + (yy-y0)**2.) - radius) / width)**2 )
```

I plotted xx, yy and z using contourf:

```
fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
plt.contourf(xx,yy,z)
plt.show()
```

It is what I got:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZWdF.png)

Then I tried to fit the z using my fittable class:

```
p_init = ringGaussian() #bounds={"x0":[0., 20.], "y0":[0., 20.]}
fit_p = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
p = fit_p(p_init, xx, yy, z)
# It is the parameter I got:
<ringGaussian(background=133.0085329497139, amplitude=-155.53652181827655, x0=25.573499373946227, y0=25.25813520725603, radius=8.184302497405568, width=-7.273935403490675)>
```

I plotted the model:

```
fig = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
plt.contourf(xx,yy,p(xx,yy))
plt.show()
```

It is what I got:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8Yw6.png)

Originally, I also tried to include the derivative in my class:

```
@staticmethod
def fit_deriv(x, y, background, amplitude, x0, y0, radius, width):
    g = (np.sqrt((x-x0)**2. + (y-y0)**2.) - radius) / width
    z = amplitude * np.exp( -g**2 )

    dg_dx0 = - (x-x0)/np.sqrt((x-x0)**2. + (y-y0)**2.)
    dg_dy0 = - (y-y0)/np.sqrt((x-x0)**2. + (y-y0)**2.)
    dg_dr0 = - 1/width
    dg_dw0 = g * -1/width

    dz_dB = 1.
    dz_dA = z / amplitude
    dz_dx0 = -2 * z * g**3 * dg_dx0
    dz_dy0 = -2 * z * g**3 * dg_dy0
    dz_dr0 = -2 * z * g**3 * dg_dr0
    dz_dw0 = -2 * z * g**3 * dg_dw0

    return [dz_dB, dz_dA, dz_dx0, dz_dy0, dz_dr0, dz_dw0]
```

But it returned "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence."

I'm quite desperate now. Can anyone suggest some possible solutions? or alternative ways to implement the ring gaussian fit in python?

Many many thanks~~~

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation is OK (I did not try or check your `fit_deriv` implementation).

The issue is just that your fit doesn't converge because the initial model parameters are too far from the true values, so the optimiser fails. When I run your code, I get this warning:

```
WARNING: The fit may be unsuccessful; check fit_info['message'] for more information. [astropy.modeling.fitting]
```

If you change to model parameters so that your model roughly matches the data, the fit succeeds:

```
p_init = ringGaussian(x0=11, y0=11)
```

To check how your model compares with the data, you can use `imshow` to display data and model images (or also e.g. residual images):

```
plt.imshow(z)
plt.imshow(p_init(xx,yy))
plt.imshow(p(xx,yy))
```

Comment: Hi Christoph, Thank you for your prompt reply. In reality, the ring in an image may appear anywhere (i.e. I could not guess where it is). Is there anyway to improve my current algorithm so that I don't need to guess? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a source search followed by source fitting. It's a non-trivial problem and the algorithms to choose depend on your data and how much time you want to invest to do something simple or fancy. There's a ton of papers in astronomy and image processing concerning source search and making catalogs and fitting sources. Are you aware of https://photutils.readthedocs.io ? Trying a few of the methods available there might be a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's really helpful! I'll have a look at the library.